# How to fetch the value of Selected text from Popup Using Alchemy Plugin

Tags: a4t

pLugin having popup Page with one Drop down List and one Submit button. now  want to selected text from Dropdown list will pass in CMS text field.

Need to implement below Function in Main Command.
**Question : How i fetch the popup JS event listener value in my main Command ???????**

```
execute: function (selection) {

  $evt.addEventHandler(p.popup, "submit", function (event)
 {
                   try {
                               var fieldBuilder;
                               var tabs = $display.getView().properties.controls.TabControl;
                               var cardCount, card;
                               cardCount = tabs.properties.cards.length;
                               card;
                               //  console.log($display.getView().properties.controls.TabControl);
                               while (cardCount--) {
                                   card = tabs.properties.cards[cardCount];
                                   if (card.getId() === "MetadataTab") {
                                       fieldBuilder = card.properties.controls.fieldBuilder;
                                       //console.log(fieldBuilder);
                                   }
                               }

                               if (fieldBuilder.getField("topic")) {

                                   ///Code For topic
                                   var set = fieldBuilder.getField("topic");

                                   var x = "someText";
                                   set.setValues([x.toString()]);
                                   console.log(fieldBuilder.getField("topic").getValues()[0]);
                               }

                               if (fieldBuilder.getField("subTopic")) {
                                   var set = fieldBuilder.getField("subTopic");

                                   var x = "sometext";
                                   set.setValues([x.toString()]);
                                   console.log(fieldBuilder.getField("subTopic").getValues()[0]);

                               }

                           }

                           catch (e) {
                               console.log("Found Error" + e);
                           }
                          // p.popup.close();
               });

I have implemented Selected DDl Value code in popUp Js as below

    controls.btnSelect.addEventListener("click", function () {

        var skillsSelect = document.getElementById("ddlTopic");
        var selectedText = skillsSelect.options[skillsSelect.selectedIndex].text;

        target.fireEvent("submit", { content: selectedText });
    });
```

**need below content in Main command.js "Submit" handler Event.**
       **target.fireEvent("submit", { content: selectedText });**

Thanks in Advanced!!!!!!

Comment: I'm not sure, How you have trying to achieve using a popup to return a value to cme field, But I have done similar CustomURL popup to return a value to that cme field. reference https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011/concept_34A7EEA7E40649E79052454C70ED3431#addHistory=true&filename=CM_Schemas.xml&docid=concept_34A7EEA7E40649E79052454C70ED3431&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_34A7EEA7E40649E79052454C70ED3431

Comment: Also, refer to Item Selector Custom URL eXtension https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/blob/master/Item%20Selector/trunk/SDLTridion.Examples.ItemSelector/ItemSelector.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Code which i used to fetch the Submit Event of popupPage.js in Command.js

> In popupPage.js we need to declare ._excecute Command as below

```
Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins.Topic.Views.Popup.prototype._execute = function (event) {

//logic of dropdown control

var Result =//logic Result;

target.fireEvent("submit", { content: Result });

});
```

> Now fetch the Event and Result in Command.js.

```
execute: function (target) {

 $evt.addEventHandler(p.popup, "submit", function (event) {

//you will get your Result in event.data.content

var val = event.data.content;

});
}
```

> Happy Coding.....